# Обрезка искаженных изображений

Tags: python, numpy, pil, cv2

Создал программу, которая сшивает изображения в панораму, и для сохранения масштабности программа искажает контуры результата. Осталось довести этот результат до конца.
Была идея найти крайние нулевые пиксели и обрезать фотку по ним, так получится прямоугольное изображение, уже без искажений контура, а так же при обрезке теряется минимальное количество информации.
Вот код, который должен это сделать, однако почему-то он не находит эти самые нулевые пиксели(

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def crop_image(img):
distorted_image = np.array(img)
first_zero_row = np.where(distorted_image.sum(axis=1) == 0)
first_zero_column = np.where(distorted_image.sum(axis=0) == 0)

# Обрезать искаженное изображение по первым нулевым пикселям, если они существуют
if first_zero_row.size > 0 and first_zero_column.size > 0:
cropped_image = distorted_image[:first_zero_row, :first_zero_column]
else:
cropped_image = distorted_image
return cropped_image
```

Если Вам не сложно, помогите доработать код, или может вообще начать заново.
Вот пример искаженного изображения:
[image]

А вот пример того, что должно получиться на выходе:
[image]

То есть изображение должно обрезаться вот так:
[image]
Другими словами программа должна найти наибольший прямоуглоьник, в который влезает как можно больше изоражения.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Пока код не запускал, а Вы уверены что там 0 а не `tuple RGB` или `RGBA` ? Думаю Вам нужно просто посмотреть как именно найти "черный" (пустой) пиксель, на тестовом изображении например шахматной доске из "черных" и белых пикселей.

Comment: `'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'` ну вот же вылезает ошибка, доработайте пожалуйста вопрос чтобы было видно как Вы запускаете и что у Вас не получается, нужен минимально воспроизводимый пример демонстирующий проблему, и результаты или ошибки

Comment: Я бы "нарисовал" максимально большой прямоугольник, и уменьшал бы его до тех пор, пока в каждом из углов прямоугольника не будет абсолютно чёрных пикселей.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, да, вот только я тут понял, что таким способом, изображение обрежется только в двух "направлениях" (слева и сверху), и я думаю, что добраться, до 2 других сторон буудет достаточно проблемотично, я вот теперь не знаю даже, может действительно сделать, так как: найти  наибольший прямоуглоьник, в который влезает как можно больше изоражения.

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn , идея хорошая. Я так понимаю, что мы будем уменьшать его равномерно, то есть по итогу этот прямоугольник будет по центру, а что если искаженное изображенное изображение будет не симметричным, тогда, возможно, мы обрежем лишнего.

Comment: Слышал про функцию cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix, возможно она здесь поможет, вот только у меня никак не получается с ней разобраться.

Comment: @ArseniyLaptev можно кропнуть [так](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-crop-an-image-using-the-numpy-module/) остается только поработать с массивом поискать в них строчки и колонки содержащие пиксели ниже порога, верхний левый пиксель если не ошибаюсь [22,22,22] далее в линии [14,14,14] для правого и нижнего варианта возможно понадобится отдельный цикл